# Почему создаются лишние элементы?

Tags: javascript, html, slider

Добавил всего 3 слайда

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>test</title>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/lightslider.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/lightbox.css">

</head>
<body>
<!-- Галлерея -->
<ul id="imageGallery">
    <!-- Слайд 1 -->
    <li data-thumb="img/big_33798_724.jpg"><a href="img/big_33798_724.jpg" data-lightbox="roadtrip"><img src="img/big_33798_724.jpg" alt=""></a></li>
    <!-- Слайд 2 -->
    <li data-thumb="img/big_33798_724.jpg"><a href="img/big_33798_724.jpg" data-lightbox="roadtrip"><img src="img/big_33798_724.jpg" alt=""></a></li>
    <!-- Слайд 3 -->
    <li data-thumb="img/big_33798_724.jpg"><a href="img/big_33798_724.jpg" data-lightbox="roadtrip"><img src="img/big_33798_724.jpg" alt=""></a></li>
</ul>
<footer>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/lightslider.js"></script>
    <script src="js/lightbox.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#imageGallery').lightSlider({
            gallery:true,
            item:1,
            loop:true,
            thumbItem:9,
            slideMargin:0,
            enableDrag: false,
            currentPagerPosition:'left',
            onSliderLoad: function(el) {
                el.lightGallery({
                    selector: '#imageGallery .lslide'
                });
            }   
        });  
      });
    </script>
    <script>
        lightbox.option({
          'resizeDuration': 200,
          'wrapAround': true
        })
    </script>
</footer>   
</body>
</html>
```

А в модальном окне появляется целых 5, подскажите пожалуйста, в чем ошибка. Спасибо
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все, решил!
На самом деле очень глупый вопрос :) Просто поставил в скрипте у слайдера `loop: false` ...